# I'm trying to access some json data from a my sql server

Tags: python, mysql, json

Please be advised that I'm new to python.
I tried to access data from a MySQL server with python. 
Thus far I have made the connection to the server and got the data but the trouble happens when I got to parse through the data.
I got the error as follows.

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

```
import MySQLdb
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = create_con()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select answer_option from question_answer")

    result = cur.fetchone()
    x = json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TypeError: expected string or buffer* clearly hints at the problem.

You could do `print result`  to verify the type.

--

**cursor.fetchone()**

This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a **single sequence**, or **None** if no more rows are available. Documentation reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)

==

**json.loads(s)**

This method deserialize  a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document to a Python object using this conversion table. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

--

So, I think perhaps you dont need json.loads... as result is already a python object.

Comment: The type is a tuple, not sure how I can parse through a tuple??

Comment: what are you trying to do with 'result' Or 'x' object? touple is a sequence object just like a List

Comment: thanks for your help, your answer really helped my understanding, my imported data was automatically being formatted in a tuple, I had to access each of the items independently to use the json.loads()

Answer (score 0):

json loads -> returns an object from a string representing a json object.

json dumps -> returns a string representing a json object from an object.

so your `json.loads` is looking for a string representation. So you better do json.dumps and then do json.loads.

this should fix.

```
import MySQLdb
import json

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        conn = create_con()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select answer_option from question_answer")

        result = cur.fetchone()
        x = json.dumps(result)
        x = json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cursor class returns rows as tuples.

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.excute("select answer_option from question_answer")
    result = cur.fetchone()
```

print(result) you get `("foo", )`

You can do this to get your result

```
    x = result[0]
```

OR

include `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` in your cursor to return rows as dictionaries. Then you can access them by name.

```
    cur = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.excute("select answer_option from question_answer")
    result = cur.fetchone()
```

print(result) you get `{"answer_option": "foo"}`

You can access your result like this:

```
    x = result['answer_option']
```